# Prolog :- Error in code

Tags: prolog, logic

I have been trying to solve problem

```
? − evalExp(exp(−, exp(∗, 3, 4), exp(/, 2, 3)), N ).
N = 11.333333333333334.
```

My code is working in windows but not working in ubuntu.This is my code.

```
evalExp(exp(X,L,R),N):-expr(exp(X,L,R),N).
expr(exp(-,L,R),N):-expr(L,N1),expr(R,N2),N is N1-N2.
expr(exp(+,L,R),N):-expr(L,N1),expr(R,N2),N is N1+N2.
expr(exp(*,L,R),N):-expr(L,N1),expr(R,N2),N is N1*N2.
expr(exp(/,L,R),N):-expr(L,N1),expr(R,N2),N is N1/N2.
expr(exp(**,L,0),N):-N=1.
expr(exp(**,L,R),N):-
   expr(L,N1),expr(R,N2),P is N2-1,expr(exp(**,N1,P),N3),N is N1*N3.
expr(A,N):- N is A.
```

Comment: You need to explain "not working", please. Also, which Prolog interpreter are you using? SWI?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see your base case in the code. You should have one for the code to backtrack.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your last clause, which upon backtracking will try to evaluate the expression.
It can be solved by checking that the input value (A in your clause) is a number. So the last clause should read:

```
expr(N,N):- number(N).
```

There is also a singleton variable in the clause that deals with ** with argument 0, it should read:

```
expr(exp(**,_,0),N):-N=1.
```

Comment: After doing what you said, my code is working in windows but in ubuntu it is showing false

Comment: @ChimedPalden: Check for typos in your code of Ubuntu. Your code seems fine after the suggested changes.